# Update array of objects from loop

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to loop through `orderArray` and for each `order` to `find_one_and_update` document in Mongo. **Everything good**.

The problem is when I try to loop again through `itemArray`, and for each `item` object, insert it in `product` array:

```
for order_dico in response['orderArray']:
    order = order_dico['order']                        
    db.Order.find_one_and_update(
        {"orderId":order['orderID']},
        {
            "$set":{
                "orderId":order['orderID'],
                "product":
                    [
                        ######### ######### ######### 
                        ######### here is the error
                        ######### ######### ######### 
                        for item in order['itemArray']:
                            {
                                "prodId":item['item']['sku'],
                                "quantity":item['item']['quantity'],
                                "title":item['item']['title'],
                                "pic":item['item']['thumbnailURL'],
                                "price":item['item']['price']
                            }
                    ]
                }
            }
        )
```

I got this error:

```
invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 57)
```

and this is the `order` object:

```
{
    order:{
        orderID: 1234,
        itemArray: [
                      item:{
                          itemID: 709475209,
                          sku: "1004",
                          ....
                      }
                   ]
          }
}
```

Comment: yon cant use for loop in mongo query

Comment: @VikasSharma, that's what I started to believe. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: need more information what you want achieve and how data you are populating

Comment: @VikasSharma, just solved by creating an empty array and push the objects inside the loop:
```
product=[]
        for item in order['itemArray']: 
            product.append({
                "prodId":item['item']['sku'],
                "quantity":item['item']['quantity'],
                "title":item['item']['title'],
                "pic":item['item']['thumbnailURL'],
                "price":item['item']['price']
            })
```

and inside `$set` : ``"product":product`

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot loop inside `$set`, also do you need to replace `product` or add new items to it ?

Answer (score 0):

First create an empty array and push the objects inside the loop:

```py
 for order_dico in response['orderArray']:
        order = order_dico['order']  
        product=[]
        for item in order['itemArray']: 
            product.append({
                "prodId":item['item']['sku'],
                "quantity":item['item']['quantity'],
                "title":item['item']['title'],
                "pic":item['item']['thumbnailURL'],
                "price":item['item']['price']
            })
```

And then add the resulted array in `$set`:

```
"$set":{      
         ...
         "product":product
}
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59615493/3) to the question [Update array of objects from loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615493/update-array-of-objects-from-loop) by the OP [Mike Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5600899/mike-will) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>